# javascript get object in nested child array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling with getting an object in a nested array from firebase using angularfire.

The structure looks like this:

```
users {
  <user1-key>{
    events{
      <event-key>{
        title: "event 1",
        tasks: {
          <task-key>{
            title: "task 1",
            isChecked: false
          },
          <task-key>{
            title: "task 2",
            isChecked: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },


  <user 2-key>{
    events{
      <event-key>{
        title: "event 1",
        tasks: {
          <task-key>{
            title: "task 1",
            isChecked: false
          },
          <task-key>{
            title: "task 2",
            isChecked: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I have a service that fetches items from firebase based on users:

```
app.factory("Events", function ($firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, baseUrl) {
    ref = new Firebase(baseUrl);
    refAuth = ref.getAuth();
    events = $firebaseArray(ref.child("users/" + refAuth.uid + "/events"));

    return {
        all: function() {
          return events;
        },   

        get: function (eventId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                if (events[i].$id === eventId) {
                    return events[i];
                }
            }
        },

        getTasks: function(eventId){
           for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                if (events[i].$id === eventId) {
                   return events[i].tasks;
                }
            }
        },

        getInnerTask: function(eventId, taskId){
       for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            if (events[i].$id === eventId) {
               event = events[i];
               for(var j = 0; j < event.tasks.length; j++){
                    if(event.tasks[j].$id === taskId){
                        return event.tasks[j];
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    }


    };
});
```

now in my service I am able to get events as well as a single event. but I cannot seem to be able to get a single task. only list the tasks. in getInnerTask I am using nested for loops in the hope that I can get the id in a similar way to getting the event ids but it is not working.

here is my controller for the single event:

```
app.controller("EventsInnerCtrl", function ($scope, $firebaseArray,$firebaseObject, $stateParams, Events) {

    $scope.event = Events.get($stateParams.eventId);

    $scope.tasks = Events.getTasks($stateParams.eventId);
    console.log($scope.tasks);

    $scope.clickTask = function(){
        $scope.task = Events.getInnerTask($stateParams.taskId);
        console.log($scope.task); // this returns "Undefined"
    }


});
```

Its worth noting that my events output looks like this:

[Events console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGssh.png)

and my tasks out put looks different (Lacks the $id field in output):

[Tasks console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTRA2.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
getInnerTask: function(eventId, taskId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        if (events[i].$id === eventId) {
            event = events[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < event.tasks.length; j++) {
                if (event.tasks[j].$id === taskId) {
                    return event.tasks[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My guess is `event` is not in the current scope, may be you are not able to access it... how about using `var` keyword with `event`

Comment: I have tried every variation I could think of but still no luck